# Jquery Button Click Chaining

Tags: jquery

I have Created a simple Jquery Code..

The Code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('#Button1').click(function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#Textbox1').animate({ width: '300px', height: '75px' })
            })
           </script>
```

Now i want to chain the result So On clicking the button another time
I get the Original Textbox Size back

I tried this code below but it does not work. Any suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('#Button1').click(function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#Textbox1').animate({ width: '300px', height: '75px' }) })
                .animate({ width: '100px', height: '10px' })
                });
           </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to execute two *different* functions on alternate clicks. At the first click you change the size and on the second click you change it back to the original. You can use [`toggle` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) for that:

```
$('#Button1').toggle(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#Textbox1').stop().animate({ width: '300px', height: '75px' });
}, function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#Textbox1').stop().animate({ width: '100px', height: '10px' });
});
```

**Update:** [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gf7XM/). Apparently someone disagrees with my answer. This should show that it works.

Comment: @downvoter: Please explain. What did I do wrong? Especially as all the other answers work in a similar way...

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Button1').click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#Textbox1').animate({ width: '300px', height: '75px' }, function() {
            $('#Textbox1').animate({ width: '100px', height: '10px' });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is using the first animation's `complete` callback function in order to start the second animation.

Or if you don't want to "chain" the animations, and instead want to perform the opposite animation on a second click (which is a *toggle*, not a *chain*), try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Button1').click(click1);

    function click1(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#Textbox1').animate({ width: '300px', height: '75px' }, function() {
            $('#Button1').unbind('click');
            $('#Button1').click(click2);
        });
    }

    function click2(evt) { 
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#Textbox1').animate({ width: '100px', height: '10px' }, function() {
            $('#Button1').unbind('click');
            $('#Button1').click(click1);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/52A3w/1

Comment: `animate` is automatically added to the `fx` queue. Calling it in the callback will have the same effect as chaining it. This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Felix - Yes, I noticed.  The terminology in the OP is unclear.  On my first read-through I saw "i want to chain" and assumed he wanted the animations to execute one after the other.  What he really wants is a toggle, not a chain.

Comment: Be carful with your edit. You are assigning event handlers over and over again without removing them.... this will result in chaos ;)

Answer (score 0):

something like that should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $('#Button1').click(function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
             var button=$(this);
             if (button.hasClass('widecontent') {
                 $('#Textbox1').animate({ width: '100px', height: '10px' });
                  } else       
                {
                  $('#Textbox1').animate({ width: '300px', height: '75px' }) });
                }
       button.toggleClass('widecontent');
 });
</script>
```